# SAS Proc SQL Trim not working?

Tags: sas, trim, proc-sql

I have a problem that seems pretty simple (probably is...) but I can't get it to work.

The variable 'name' in the dataset 'list' has a length of 20.  I wish to conditionally select values into a macro variable, but often the desired value is less than the assigned length.  This leaves trailing blanks at the end, which I cannot have as they disrupt future calls of the macro variable.

I've tried trim, compress, btrim, left(trim, and other solutions but nothing seems to give me what I want (which is 'Joe' with no blanks).  This seems like it should be easier than it is.....  Help.

```
data list;
    length id 8 name $20;
    input id name $;
cards;
1 reallylongname
2 Joe
;
run;

proc sql;
    select trim(name) into :nameselected
    from list
    where id=2;
run;

%put ....&nameselected....;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, there is an option, TRIMMED, to do what you want.

```
proc sql noprint;
    select name into :nameselected TRIMMED
    from list
    where id=2;
quit;
```

Also, end `PROC SQL` with `QUIT;`, not `RUN;`.

Comment: @Jeff had an answer that worked, but this one is cleaner.  Thanks.

Comment: I've never seen this before. Cool. +1.

Answer (score 6):

It works if you specify a separator:

```
proc sql;
    select trim(name) into :nameselected separated by ''
    from list
    where id=2;
run;
```

Comment: Yep, that did it.  Thanks, Jeff.  Seems like what I have should work, though.....

Comment: Interestingly, the separator doesn't even have to blank.

Comment: @pyll For some reason, they chose to make TRIMMED the default with separated-by and NOTRIM the default otherwise.  I have no idea why.